# display the icon on kanban object

Tags: xml, odoo

I want display a boolean icon on kanban object, the code that I have made :

```
<div class="oe_kanban_content">
    <div><b><field name="name"/></b></div>
    <div>
        <field name="project_id"/><br/>
        <t t-if="record.date_deadline.raw_value and record.date_deadline.raw_value lt (new Date())" t-set="red">oe_kanban_text_red</t>
        <span t-attf-class="#{red || ''}"><i><field name="date_deadline"/></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="oe_kanban_footer_left">
        <span groups="project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks" title="Remaining hours">
            <span class="oe_e">N</span>
            <t t-esc="Math.round(record.remaining_hours.raw_value)"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="oe_kanban_footer_left" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <t t-raw="record.message_summary.raw_value"/>
        <field name="categ_ids"/>
    </div>
        <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right">
            <img t-att-src="kanban_image('res.users', 'image_small', record.user_id.raw_value)" t-att-title="record.user_id.value" width="24" height="24" class="oe_kanban_avatar pull-right"/>
            <div class="pull-left" groups="base.group_user">
                <field name="issue_related" widget="priority"/>
                <field name="kanban_state" widget="kanban_state_selection"/>
                <field name="priority" widget="priority"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

issue_related = field.boolean
,I have not found a way to display the icon on kanban boolean object

Comment: What do you mean by a "boolean icon"?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "issue_related=field.boolean" in Kanban view, it'll show "true" if selected other wise it'll be blank.

[image: For example see this image:]

Can you explain what does Boolean button means? If you can upload a screen shot what you need.